# How to find each row and column data type in pandas dataframe using apply, map or applymap?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, complex-data-types

I have dataframe as shown in image. I want each row and columns data type using apply/map/applymap.
How to get this datatype? Some columns have mixed datatype as highlighted e.g. list and str, some have list and dict.

[![samplepandasdataframe][1]][1]

[1]:

Comment: What is your expected dataframe?, could you put your data as code, please?

Comment: you should rather modify code which generates this data.

Comment: This is CSV file data, I want information for each column that is it structured or unstructured.

Comment: expected output will be as following: column1 -> string , coumn2 -> list and dict, column3 -> list, coulmn4 -> dict

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to have the evaluated type value of every cell you can use

```
def check_type(x):
     try: 
        return type(eval(x)) 
     except Exception as e:
        return type(x)

df.applymap(check_type)
```

If you want to also get how many datatypes you have you can use things like

```
df.applymap(type).value_counts()
```

or if you want to get the values for all of the dataframe instead of by column

```
np.unique(df.applymap(type).astype(str).values, return_counts=True)
```

Comment: `df.applymap(type)` this giving <class 'str'> for list or dict. I want <class 'list'> or <class 'dict'> for respective data.

Comment: but that means they are string. You can evaluate all the cells and check the types but it would be slow. I am changing the solution. Please uv and accept the answer

Comment: Also please never do this on data you got from external resources. This evaluates every cells code therefore if there is a malicious code there you would evaluate that code block too. Please use it with caution.

Comment: How to get column names which has <class 'dict'> and <class 'list'> @alparslanmimaroğlu?

Comment: should be like this `df[df.isin(["<class 'dict'>", "<class 'list'>"]).any(axis=0)]`