# How to get datatypes of each row using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this.

| Name | Age |
| --- | --- |
| John | 20.5 |
| Alice | 39.1 |
| Pam | 41.0 |
| 203921 | Hope |

I want to create a new column called "Name_Type" that returns as follows:

| Name | Name_Type |
| --- | --- |
| John | True |
| Alice | True |
| Pam | True |
| 203921 | False |

| Age | Age_Type |
| --- | --- |
| 20.5 | True |
| 39.1 | True |
| 41.0 | True |
| Hope | False |

I want to check if the column, Name, is a STRING. I will do the same for Age, checking if it is a FLOAT.

Comment: `df['Name_Type'] = `df['Age'].str.isnumeric()`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find each row and column data type in pandas dataframe using apply, map or applymap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69914296/how-to-find-each-row-and-column-data-type-in-pandas-dataframe-using-apply-map-o)

Comment: @QuangHoang hi i think i can us isnumeric for an integer and string check, thanks! however for integer and float check, I'm not sure...

Comment: @HuzaifaAzhar hi, it is a little different from what I'm asking for...

Comment: pd.to_numeric would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect this to work in your case:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['John', 'Alice', 'Pam', 203921], 'Age':[20.5, 39.1, 41.0, 'Hope']})
df['Name_Type'] = [True if type(x) == str else False for x in df.Name]
df['Age_Type'] = [True if type(x) == float else False for x in df.Age]
print(df)
```

Result:

```
     Name   Age  Name_Type  Age_Type
0    John  20.5       True      True
1   Alice  39.1       True      True
2     Pam  41.0       True      True
3  203921  Hope      False     False
```

When all values are strings, this solution should work:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['John', 'Alice', 'Pam', '203921'], 'Age':['20.5', '39.1', '41.0', 'Hope']})

def is_float(x):
    try:
        float(x)
        return True
    except:
        return False

df['Name_Type'] = ~df.Name.str.isnumeric()    
df['Age_Type'] = df.Age.apply(is_float)
```